# How can I save .playground file devloped in Xcode to .swiftpm

Tags: xcode, swift-playground

How can I save .playground file devloped in Xcode to .swiftpm. It's Apple requirement to submit the app in swftpm format to be eligible for Swift student challenge 2024. I am struggling for more than 24 hours and couldn't find a way. When I followed instructions to create Swift package, I couldn't run the app at all.  Appriciate your help!

Followed instructions how to create Swift package by restructuring the code, but the app is not executable when unzip and try to run the code in Xcode or playground. I am expecting the code from .swiftpm should run as is without any changes

Answer (score 0):

Create a Swift Playgrounds App project in Xcode to create an app project that you can use in Xcode and the Swift Playgrounds app.

Creating a Swift Playgrounds app project in Xcode will fulfill the [Swift Student Challenge requirement that the submission be an app playground](https://developer.apple.com/swift-student-challenge/eligibility/).